# How to find the difference among two columns in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to find the difference among two Columns in SQL Server which they are DataTime Type using only C# Code and No LINQ .

```
public class PrintTheQ
{
    public DateTime LastStatusUpdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedToQueue { get; set; }
}

public static PrintTheQ TestQ ()
{
        PrintTheQ TheQ = new PrintTheQ();

        string CS = "data source =(local); database = Sample1; Integrated Security=SSPI";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select *from TelecomTable WHERE AddedToQueue  >= DATEADD (day, -2, GetDate()) ", connection);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                TheQ.AddedToQueue = Convert.ToDateTime((reader, "AddedToQueue"));
                TheQ.LastStatusUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime((reader, "LastStatusUpdate"));
            }
        }

        return TheQ;
}
```

Comment: If you just want to know the difference between two dates from the same record you could just ask to the database engine to calculate the DateDiff and produce a column with the difference

Comment: i am gonna try it . i will get back to you then

Comment: but if i dont want to use the Database or even the LINQ syntax and just the C# syntax ! how is going to work then

Comment: @Steve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834301/how-to-save-the-data-from-sql-in-a-list-then-find-the-max-only-using-c-sharp-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your requirement to not handle this task at the database level and not using linq then all you need is to add a property to your class and this property is calculated every time you need to read it (only get, if you want to change it, then change the operands)

Just add a readonly property to your class

```
public class PrintTheQ
{
    public DateTime LastStatusUpdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedToQueue { get; set; }
    public int DayDiff
    {
        get {return (int)(LastStatusUpdate - AddedToQueue).TotalDays;}
    }
}
```

This example calculates the difference in days, but of course, the [TimeSpan structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) created subtracting the highest date from the lowest date can give you the difference also in TotalHours, TotalMinutes, TotalSeconds, TotalMilliseconds and even Ticks

This is probably the most logical way to do this thing. Minimal impact on the current code with no foreach, no database code to change, no change to your actual loading code. Also if you change the value of LastStatusUpdate the DayDiff property will be automatically recalculated next time you read it.

Comment: hey Steve . thanks alot for the explanation.. i will try it and get back to you later .

Comment: hey steve i get back to you with another query so . firs of all how i could save my  results from SQL in a LIST becasue i need to find the max of difference and that would be achived during a List ...right ?!

Comment: I suggest you to post a new question. It is better to do this way than asking directly to me. More persons will look at your question and your probability to get a correct answer will raise.

Answer (score 0):

try :
`SELECT DATEDIFF(year, @startdate, @enddate)`

year represents the period of measure you want to return it could be month or day

Comment: i am gonna try it . i will get back to you then

Comment: but if i dont want to use the Database or even the LINQ syntax and just the C# syntax ! how is going to work then