# How to save the Data from SQL in a List then find the max only using C# and no LINQ

Tags: c#

How to save my data from Sql in a List ?! i would like to save the data which are holding in an Instance from the class in a List then find the max of value ...take a look at code please !

public class PrintQueue

```
{
    public static TheQFromDB GetQ()

    {
        TheQFromDB TheQ = new TheQFromDB();

        using (SqlConnection connection = DBConnection.GetTheQFromDB())
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select *from PrintQueue WHERE AddedToQueue  >= DATEADD (day, -2, GetDate()) ", connection);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t\t\t{2}\t\t{3}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(4), reader.GetName(5));
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        TheQ.Id = (Int32)reader["Id"];
                        TheQ.PrinterName = (string)reader["PrinterName"];
                        TheQ.AddedToQueue = (DateTime)reader["AddedToQueue"];
                        TheQ.LastStatusUpdate = (DateTime)reader["LastStatusUpdate"];
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t\t\t{2}\t\t{3} ={4}", reader.GetSqlInt32(0), reader.GetSqlString(1), reader.GetSqlDateTime(4), reader.GetSqlDateTime(5), TheQ.SecondsDiff+"sec");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return TheQ;
                }

                return null;

            }
        }
```

Comment: What part of the code is giving you problems? Its hard to help when there is not a concrete problem

Comment: BTW: IDataReader.Read() does move to the next record so in `if(datareader.read()` you are skipping the first row of data

Comment: It is not clear what is the field that you want to consider for calculating a _max value_

Comment: @Steve . i want to get the difference then find the max from the  Difference .. i will try what you had posted to me

Comment: Then you need to just use the SecondDiffs instead of LastStatusUpdate. Of course you need to adapt the parameter type passed as out to GetQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a list of your objects then you need to define one, fill it while you read from the database and return it from your method.

The problem with the *max value* (assuming that you consider for max value the date contained in the *LastStatusUpdate* could be solved passing an *out* variable of type DateTime

```
public static List<TheQFromDB> GetQ(out DateTime maxValue)
{
    // Initialize the maxValue 
    maxValue = DateTime.MinValue;

    // The list with your objects....
    List<TheQFromDB> elements = new List<TheQFromDB>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = DBConnection.GetTheQFromDB())
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select *from PrintQueue WHERE AddedToQueue  >= DATEADD (day, -2, GetDate()) ", connection);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            // Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t\t\t{2}\t\t{3}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(4), reader.GetName(5));

            // Loop over the data returned by the reader
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                // Build the current instance for the current record
                // Do not declare this object outside the loop or your list
                // will have the same values from the last record
                TheQFromDB TheQ = new TheQFromDB();
                TheQ.Id = (Int32)reader["Id"];
                TheQ.PrinterName = (string)reader["PrinterName"];
                TheQ.AddedToQueue = (DateTime)reader["AddedToQueue"];
                TheQ.LastStatusUpdate = (DateTime)reader["LastStatusUpdate"];

                // Now check if the current record is 'greater' than 
                // a saved value from a previous record.
                if(TheQ.LastStatusUpdate > maxValue)
                   maxValue = TheQ.LastStatusUpdate;


                // Add the current element to the list
                elements.Add(TheQ);
            }

            // Return to the caller.
            return elements;
        }
     }
}
```

Now you can call this method in this way

```
List<TheQFromDB> result = GetQ(out DateTime lastUpdateValue);
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine(lastUpdateValue.ToString());
foreach(var q in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t\t\t{2}\t\t{3} ={4}", q.ID, q.PrinterName,  
                     q.AddedToQueue.ToString(), q.LastStatusUpdate,  
                     q.SecondsDiff+"sec");
}
```

Comment: Where i call this Method ! do you mean at Main () ? this part was not clear for me .

Comment: Whenever you need that list. In main it is a possibility

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870656/how-to-find-the-max-or-the-highest-value-in-list-using-just-c-sharp-code-and-n?noredirect=1#comment98402309_55870656